# Standard Lists Import in Trello

Tags: trello

I am using Trello for project management and have several standard lists that will be used over and over. Is their a way to import them to each card instead of having to write the same lists for every card?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to say:

> Is their a way to import them to each *board* instead of having to write the same lists for every *board*?

Because if that is what you are trying to do, then I might have a solution for you.

1. Make a template board with the *standard* lists that you will use over and over again.
2. While you're at it, name the *standard* labels that you might want to use again and again as well.
3. Whenever you want to make a new board with the *standard* lists and labels, just go to this template board and click the **Copy Board** option in the right hand **Menu** (you may have to click **More** first)
4. At this point you can select which you want to copy this board to and whether you want to copy any cards that you may have in the template board. The latter works well if there are some *standard* cards you want to copy across to the new board.